# "Cursor to selected" does not go to the center of selected vertices

Tags: vertices, origin

I'm trying to set the origin of an object to be at the midpoint of all its vertices. So my technique is:

- Go to Edit mode
- Select all vertices (by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
- Cursor to selected

For some reason, however, it does not go to the center. It's almost at the center but still a little off. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to set the origin of an object to the midpoint of the vertices? Thanks!

[image: cursor does not go to midpoint of vertices]

Comment: The image indicates 12 vertices selected so maybe the barycenter is not as it seems to be visually

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Some obscure vertices that I couldn't see were selected. Thanks :)

Comment: Also you still can make the cursor be located at the center of selection by changing Pivot Point to Bounding Box prior to snapping it to selection.